# Login + Navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, authentication

When my log in class and call the activity_Main with navigation drawer can not navigate the menus. When I start the application by activity_main navigation drawer works correctly.

Error:
Method invocation 'drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.
Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or @NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check nullability contracts, e.g. report possible NullPointerException errors.
More complex contracts can be defined using @Contract annotation, for example:
@Contract("*, null -> null") — method returns null if its second argument is null @Contract("*, null -> null; _, !null -> !null") — method returns null if its second argument is null and not-null otherwise @Contract("true -> fail") — a typical assertFalse method which throws an exception if true is passed to it 
The inspection can be configured to use custom @Nullable
@NotNull annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used) 'setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)' is deprecated less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope.

Login

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

    Button email_sign_in_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    email_sign_in_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

    });
}
```

Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment()).commit();
}
```

Comment: This question is not clear at all. Please consider editing it to clearly state a specific question and show the code you've tried to solve the issue.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe Okay, is done.

Answer (score 0):

This log only says that the Navigation drawer **COULD** be null, if it is not found by the provided id, and then it would produce an Null Pointer Exception.

If you insert

```
if(drawer != null){
     drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle)
}
```

Or

```
  assert drawer != null
  drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle)
```

This warning in the log will disapper, but this NullPointer check is not necessary in fact.

The second part of the log indicates, that you use the deprecated Method

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener);
```

To fix that, easily call

```
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
```

**But all these things are not necessary !! Your App will also run if you Keep everything as it is, these changes will only remove the log warnings !**

Comment: Hey thanks, but i try, But it did not work , I think the problem is the " Toggle" . When I call the screen it does not carry the " hamburger " menu.  (Bad english)

Comment: but the logcat warning aren't there anymore, aren't they ?